# Get the lowest value per column based on another column

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, partitioning

Per each `product_id` based on the column `year`, I would like to get the value from column `name` that would represent the earliest `name`.

| year | name | product_id | initial_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2016 | Pepsi. | 123456 | Pepsi. |
| 2017 | Pepsi co. | 123456 | Pepsi. |
| 2017 | Cola | 567890 | Cola |
| 2018 | Coca-Cola | 567890 | Cola |
| 2019 | Coca-Colas | 567890 | Cola |

I started implementing the logic in this way but there must be an easier way:

```
SELECT *,
CASE WHEN year = date_min THEN name END name_min
FROM (
SELECT *,
    MIN(year) OVER (PARTITION BY product_id) year_min
FROM table
```

Comment: PostgreSQL implements `DISTINCT ON` for this purpose. What database are you using?

Comment: @TheImpaler BigQuery SQL

Answer (score 2):

Use `FIRST_VALUE()` window function:

```
SELECT *,
       FIRST_VALUE(name) OVER (PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY year) name_min
FROM tablename;
```